# print an empty table cell if method returns no data

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in a view partial to show a students average score for each evaluation period:

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "students")%>">
    <td>
    <%= link_to "#{student.name}", 
                 student_path({student_group_id: student.student_group_id, id: student.id})%>
    </td>
    <% student.eval_count.times do |i| %>
      <td class="center"><%= student.avg_for_eval(i) %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td class="center"><%= student.avg unless student.avg.nan? %></td>
</tr>
```

I'm using this method in `student.rb` to generate the average score, and at first I couldn't figure out why I couldn't get it to generate empty rows when there was no data.

```
def evals
  evals = self.evaluations.order("eval_number").group_by(&:eval_number)
end

def eval_number_set(index)
  numbers = Evaluation.where('student_id = ?', self.id).uniq.pluck(:eval_number)
  numbers[index]
end

def avg_for_eval(i)
  scores = []
  evals = self.evals.select { |k, v| k == self.eval_number_set(i) }.values.first
  for eval in evals
    scores << eval.score
  end
  evals.empty? #(scores.sum.to_f / scores.size).round(2)  
end
```

I changed the last line of the method to `evals.empty?` as shown above and got this in the browser:

[image: browser]

Then I realized that because of `select` any evaluations the student was not present for (in the case of a new student) was not part of the dataset I was using to generate the code.

The problem, as you can see in the picture, is that the two students who only have data for the last evaluation don't have their data in the correct columns - everything has shifted to the left because no `<td>` is being produced by the view code.

So the question, then, is how can I rewrite the method code so that I get the same output, but `if scores.empty?` the method inserts `""` or `"no data"` or some other placeholder so that a `<td>` is printed in the view?

## update

I understand what's going on a bit better now.  This method:

```
def eval_number_set(index)
  numbers = Evaluation.where('student_id = ?', self.id).uniq.pluck(:eval_number)
  numbers[index]
end
```

is returning the evaluation numbers for **each** student - so when those numbers are used in the next method

```
def avg_for_eval(i)
  scores = []
  evals = self.evals.select { |k, v| k == self.eval_number_set(i) }.values.first
  for eval in evals
    scores << eval.score
  end
  evals.empty? #(scores.sum.to_f / scores.size).round(2)  
end
```

it can only pull the evaluations that a student has been present for.  back to the drawing board for now...

## update 2

I've changed the class methods as follows:

```
#returns all 'eval_number's for a given group of students 
#as the first student will have been present for all evaluations

def eval_number_set(index)
  numbers = self.student_group.students.first.evals.keys
  # numbers = Evaluation.where('student_id = ?', self.id).uniq.pluck(:eval_number)
  numbers[index]
end

#attempts to match the first present 'eval_number' for a given student against
#the first number in the set of all 'eval_number's and react accordingly
def avg_for_eval(i)
  scores = []
  if self.evals.keys[i] == self.eval_number_set(i)
    "match"
  else
    "no_match"
  end  
end
```

this matched all the students who were present for every evaluation, but did not match any evaluations for the students who missed some.  I changed the code to the following

```
  def avg_for_eval(i)
    scores = []
    if self.evals.keys[i] == self.eval_number_set(i)
      "#{self.evals.keys[i]} vs #{self.eval_number_set(i)}"
    else
      "#{self.evals.keys[i]} vs #{self.eval_number_set(i)}"
    end          
  end
```

and it returned the following in the browser:

[image: new problem]

so I tried to add a counter in the if statement such that if the statement matched, it would increment the key being tried, otherwise it would stay on the same key:

```
  def avg_for_eval(i)
    scores = []
    key_match = 0
    if self.evals.keys[key_match] == self.eval_number_set(i)
      "#{self.evals.keys[i]} vs #{self.eval_number_set(i)}"
      key_match += 1
    else
      "#{self.evals.keys[i]} vs #{self.eval_number_set(i)}"
    end  
  end
```

which produces this:

[image]

and makes sense - the count incrementing doesn't take any real effect because of the way it's being called.  but while i think that I'm now closer to the effect I want, i'm not sure how to make it happen!

## update 3

closer still...I've changed things so that the keys are read in reverse, so all of the data is being **read** - but I'd still like the data to be **printed** with the most recent on the right (see picture below).  the model method code now looks like this:

```
  def eval_number_set(index)
    numbers = self.student_group.students.first.evals.keys.reverse
    # numbers = Evaluation.where('student_id = ?', self.id).uniq.pluck(:eval_number)
    numbers[index]
  end
  
  def avg_for_eval(i)
    scores = []
    eval_number = self.eval_number_set(i)
    if self.evals.keys.reverse[i] == eval_number
      for eval in self.evals.values[i] 
        scores << eval.score if self.evals.values[i]
      end
      scores
    else
      "no data"
    end  
  end
```

which returns the following, which I've annotated so you can understand what it is that I'm looking for a bit more clearly:

[image]

## update 4

Calling `student.evals` returns the following (for student with `id` 32):

```
{29=>[
  #<Evaluation id: 1949, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 29>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1950, score: 4, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", student_id: 32, goal_id: 64, eval_number: 29>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1951, score: 5, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", student_id: 32, goal_id: 65, eval_number: 29>], 
30=>[
  #<Evaluation id: 1957, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", student_id: 32, goal_id: 65, eval_number: 30>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1956, score: 2, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", student_id: 32, goal_id: 64, eval_number: 30>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1955, score: 1, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:43", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 30>], 
31=>[
  #<Evaluation id: 1968, score: 2, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 70, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1967, score: 2, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 69, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1966, score: 1, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 68, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1965, score: 1, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 67, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1964, score: 1, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 66, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1963, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 65, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1962, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 64, eval_number: 31>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1961, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", updated_at: "2013-08-28 11:26:56", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 31>], 
32=>[
  #<Evaluation id: 1983, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 69, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1982, score: 2, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 68, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1981, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 67, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1980, score: 4, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 66, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1979, score: 4, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 65, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1978, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 64, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1977, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 32>, 
  #<Evaluation id: 1984, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", updated_at: "2013-08-29 19:31:48", student_id: 32, goal_id: 70, eval_number: 32>]
}
```

Comment: "link_to "#{student.name}", student_path(...)". This line could be rewrited to "link_to student.name, student_path(...)"

Comment: ah good catch, not sure why that's like that

Comment: Would something like `def avg_for_eval(index)
 Evaluation.where('student_id = ? and eval_number = ?', self.id, index).sum()
end` work?

Comment: FWIW. I would avoid using word eval in your variable names. IMO its too close to the reserved word eval which will execute any ruby code you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working finally with the code below - but if someone can tell me a better way to do this, I'm happy to grant them the bounty.

in `_student_list.html.erb`

```
<table class="fixed">
  <tbody>      
    <% group.students.each_with_index do |student, index| %>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <% if index == 0 %>
        <% student.eval_count.times do |i| %>                                             
          <th class="center">Evaluation <%= i + 1 %></th>
        <% end %>
        <th><%= "Student average" if student.eval_count > 0  %></th>
      <% end %>

    </tr>
    <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "students")%>">
      <td>
        <%= link_to student.name, student_path({student_group_id: student.student_group_id, id: student.id})%>
      </td>
      <% student.student_group.eval_count.times do |i| %>
        <td class="center"><%= student.avg_for_eval(i) %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="center"><%= student.avg unless student.avg.nan? %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% reset_cycle("students") %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in `student.rb`

```
  def eval_number_set(index)
    numbers = self.student_group.students.first.evals.keys
    numbers[index]
  end

  def reverse_eval_number_set(index)
    numbers = self.student_group.students.first.evals.keys.reverse
    numbers[index]
  end

  def avg_for_eval(i)
    scores = []
    eval_number = self.reverse_eval_number_set(i)
    count_differential = (self.student_group.eval_count - self.eval_count) - i
    if self.student_group.eval_count == self.eval_count
      for eval in self.evals.values[i] 
        scores << eval.score
      end
      (scores.sum.to_f / scores.size).round(2)
    else
      if self.evals.values[count_differential]
        for eval in self.evals.values[count_differential]
          scores << eval.score
        end
        (scores.sum.to_f / scores.size).round(2)
      else
        "no data"
      end  
    end  
  end
```

Comment: is `group` and `student.student_group` the same object?

Comment: yeah, in some of the views there's an each block where each student_group is iterated through as `group`

Comment: so why are you calling `student.student_group.eval_count` instead of `group.eval_count`? Also, could you give some example of what in `evals` hash please?

Comment: good catch about group.eval_count - i'll edit post with `evals` hash

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

You should change *eval_count* method or use constant value to make 4 cells. For example,

```
4.times do |i|
  <td class="center"><%= student.avg_for_eval(i) %></td>
end
```

**END OF UPDATE**

You can try this approach:

```
def avg_for_eval(i)
  scores = Array.new(4)
  evals = self.evals.select { |k, v| k == self.eval_number_set(i) }.values.first
  evals.each_with_index do |eval, i|
    scores[i] = eval.score
  end
  (scores.sum.to_f / scores.size).round(2)  
end
```

Pay attention to *scores* array initialization. In this method [nil,nil,nil,nil] is created initially. Scores would be equal to [first_score, second_score, nil, nil] for students with only two marks.

It leads to possible mistake: result of method would be

```
(first_score + second_score) / 4
```

Comment: i like the idea, but it's still not working for much the reason - i think i need a method other than select.

Comment: Checkout my update, please. I think, I found reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

After your last update, modify the view like this:

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "students")%>">
<td>
<%= link_to "#{student.name}", 
             student_path({student_group_id: student.student_group_id, id: student.id})%>
</td>
<% student.eval_count.times do |i| %>
  <td class="center"><%= student.avg_for_eval(student.eval_count - i) %></td>
<% end %>
<td class="center"><%= student.avg unless student.avg.nan? %></td>
</tr>
```

Basically, display them in revers order

Comment: This didn't answer my question, per se, but it's the best of the answers in that it led me in the right direction the most.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `group.eval_count` is the max number of `eval_count`.

**View**

```
<table class="fixed">
  <thead>      
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <% group.eval_count.times do |i| %>                                             
      <th class="center">Evaluation <%= i + 1 %></th>
      <% end %>
      <th><%= "Student average" if group.eval_count > 0  %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% group.students.each do |student| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "students")%>">
      <td>
        <%= link_to student.name, 
                    student_path({
                      student_group_id: student.student_group_id, 
                      id: student.id
                      })%>
      </td>
      <% group.eval_count.times do |i| %>
      <td class="center"><%= student.avg_for_eval(i+1) %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="center"><%= student.avg unless student.avg.nan? %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% reset_cycle("students") %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you don't want to iterate through all evaluation numbers (i.e. have it starting from 29) then use range like `(min..group.eval_count).each` you can also do it in reverse `(min..max).to_a.reverse.each`. Figure out the `max` and `min` from your data should be fairly trivial.

**student.rb**

```
def avg_for_eval(i)
  # nil evaluated as false hence this works...
  if evaluations_with_sum[i]
     (evaluations_with_sum[i].sum / evaluations_with_sum[i].size).round(2)
  else
    'no data'
  end  
end

private
def evaluations_with_sum
  # memoize as hash using instance variable
  # 'order' does work with symbol and the sorting will be ASC
  @evals ||= self.evaluations.order(:eval_number).inject({}) do |hash, evaluation|
    hash[evaluation.eval_number] ||= []
    hash[evaluation.eval_number] << evaluation.score
    hash
  end
end
```

Actually I think `self.evaluations.order(:eval_number).average(:score).group(:eval_number)` should give you a hash with `eval_number` as key and *sum* of `score` as value but I'm not too sure you could try it out…

Answer (score 0):

To print an empty table cell, put a non-breaking space inside the cell.

```
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
```